# A little popup when a number is clicked in message app of android device, What is it called?

Tags: android, kotlin, sms, call

I want to manipulate the below shown dialog, I am not sure what that dialog is actually called. And it would be great if anyone could help me manipulate the dialog.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xX1S.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In Simple words, just send a text message with 10 digit number from your android device's message app to your friend or someone. Now when you click the on the number in the text message you'll see a option to call the number. When you click "call" you'll get a overlay to select the sim from which you want to make a call, I want to achieve this sim selection overlay. Please note the android device's phone has not been open yet. This overlay is displayed even when the android device's dailer app is closed.

Comment: don't worry about the bot message, i think your question has enough detail for it to make sense, but i'm not sure if you'd be able to change much with this, it might just be built in functionality